# How to make overflown text of one div to seamlessly move into another div

Tags: html, css

Is there any jQuery plugin or CSS trick available which allows me to do this?

```
   +---------------+
   |This is a      |
   |very long      |
   |text in this   |
   |div which will |
   |overflow and   |
   +---------------+        

                      +---------------+
                      |spill into     |
                      |this div.      |
                      |               |
                      |               |
                      |               |
                      +---------------+
```

EDIT: These 2 divs can be located anywhere in the page and texts have to reside inside the divs.

Comment: Can the same text exist in both divs (physically, not visually)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is far from the best solution but from the top of my head I'd do it like this-ish:

http://jsfiddle.net/U79Kg/

This might not be what you're after but hopefully a pointer in the right direction!

Comment: Yes. Probably there could be some more elegant way, but this is the type of solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [column-count](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) (CSS3 only). Not sure though if you can position the second column in a different place.

```
div{
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

This jQuery plugin is designed to divide one tekst in multiple sections (columns, whatever you want to call them): http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Comment: This is not about adjacent columns actually. The 2 divs can reside anywhere in the dom.

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS only, using floating boxes like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W4bHQ/

Comment: In your demo you are actually pushing a part of the text to left and other part to right. But my original question is not that. The texts have to live inside those 2 divs. And those 2 divs can reside anywhere in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on two assumptions:

1. The same text can exist in both divs
2. 'line-height' is set to fit the div nicely

This solution uses CSS and one line of JavaScript (jQuery):
http://jsfiddle.net/wzEXZ/1/

Comment: Nice. I think you meant $("#b").scrollTop($("#a").innerHeight()); otherwise they have to be the same height. Also I guess they still have to have the same width etc.